# Burned spark plug melted cylinder head

Tags: honda, sparkplugs, pilot

I just had a catastrophic failure in my 2005 Honda Pilot.  The check engine light started flashing and the engine was running rough.  Felt like a spark plug wasn't firing.  Limped it to the shop where the mechanic reported that the spark plug in the number 5 cylinder had disintegrated due to an overhead coil,  parts of the plug were in the cylinder,  and the threads in the cylinder head had melted.  I have never heard of this being possible.  Estimated cost between $3000 (head job) and $5500 (new engine). Feedback anyone?

Comment: "overhead coil" should be "overhea***te***d coil"?

Comment: Yup - sounds perfectly possible, and typically when you damage anything at the cylinder head it's expensive. It doesn't appear like you have an on topic question here though.